# javascript canvas rescaling and drawing on image

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I use Canvas to draw over images downloaded by users, while scaling it?

Example:

1. user uploaded image
2. began to draw on it
3. zoom out and continued to draw more

All changes are applied to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you will run into is IE. IE does not support canvas but you can use a library like ex-canvas to do the same in VML.

Canvas does allow to [import images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images). When you do draw image you can set the size. I'm not sure if this is supported in VML\IE though.

```
ctx.drawImage(img,j*50,i*38,50,38);
```

Comment: yes,but when i rescale image to smaller size i lost details of image
how project image changes on smaller or bigger size to original image